# Django add label/verbose name to form errors?

Tags: python, django, forms, customization

Could not find a good answer for this.

1. I have an ajax form where I want to return form.errors in ajax response.
   The `as_json()` method seems to fit.
   But it only returns the field names in the errors, how can I add the labels too (verbose name)?
2. How to manually raise required validation errors for specific field- in which I implement conditinal required in the clean() method? I want it to be the same as if the field was actually required, using default error messeges. Not just `raise ValidationError('This field is required')` where I have to type this standard messege again.